# How is the ruby's extend syntax work?

Tags: ruby, syntax, module

I write two kind syntax for extend, but is appear different behavior,one return 50, the other return 70, anyone can explain why?

```
module Discount
  def cost
    super + 20
  end
end

class Toy
  extend Discount
  def cost
    50
  end
end

# check
Toy.new.cost #=> 50
```

But:

```
module Discount
  def cost
    super + 20
  end
end

class Toy
  def cost
    50
  end 
end

# check
Toy.new.extend(Discount).cost #=>70
```

Comment: I give more one example :
 `class Burger
  def cost
    50
  end
end

module CheeseBurger
  def cost
    super + 10
  end
end

module LargeBurger
  def cost
    super + 15
  end
end

burger = Burger.new
puts burger.extend(CheeseBurger).cost
puts burger.extend(LargeBurger).cost`

Comment: The code above output 60 and 75, looks new extend module's cost method doesn't override the old cost version

Comment: That's make me a little bit confuse

Comment: Of course, it does not override anything, it _prepends_ the module to the hierarchy tree. That is the exact reason you are able to call `super` from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first snippet you call `extend` during class declaration, i. e. on `Toy` object, which is apparently a class. It is the same as calling `Toy.extend(Discount)`.

In the second snippet you `extend` the `Toy.new`, which is apparently a `Toy` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Object#extend is simply shortcut that includes a module in the receiver's eigenclass.

for further information about eigenclasses go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass#In_Ruby